# Explorer's preview push Word in background window

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, windows-explorer, preview

I have a Windows 7 computer which have a strange behavior: when preview is enabled in explorer, I double-click on any Word document, Word is launched, the document is loaded, and immediatly explorer is in the foreground window (so Word is in the background). The whole process take less than one second.

Only with Word. Not Excel or anything.
Only on one computer (5 others are identical and installed the same day).

Comment: Which version of Word? Do you have any add-ins installed?

Comment: Word 2010, no plugins. I suspect the user to have tweaked something, but she doesn't know what it could be.

Comment: Does it happen under a different user on the computer in question?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode ?

Comment: You say, "when preview is enabled in explorer", so it does not happen when thumbnail preview is disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem with Excel.
Seems this is related to Win7 64bit with Excel 32bit

I have the latest updates.
I think this solved my problem:

1. disable preview
2. reboot
3. enable preview
4. tadaaaammmm problem solved (for me)

In the hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Does the user, by any chance, have **Single-click to open an item** selected in **Folder Options**, because double-clicking with that on will cause that to happen.

[image: Folder Options]

Answer (score 0):

Try this software,power menu:
 http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/

PowerMenu is a small application I wrote back in 1998 that some extra menu items to the windows control menu in addition to the standard "Close", "Maximize", etc options. The extra menus are: Always On Top, Transparency and Minimize To Tray.

And follow this guide:
http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/09/how-to-make-a-window-stay-always-on-top-in-windows-7/

It will bring your word window to front.

Comment: The user don't want Word always on top. She just wants Word in front when she opens it, as we always saw it until now.

Comment: May be the user has changed some settings in word because you said that this happens only for word docs.Better reinstall office.